# C++ Winsock 10093 error

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm trying to build a server in C++ which can accept multiple number of clients. For that purpose I built a winsock wrapper and using threading with boost for communication for each clients.
I encountered a strange problem when trying to accept clients, I have a loop that looks like this.

```
int clientID = 0;
listenSocket = new Socket(SocketType::TCP);
listenSocket->Bind(port);
listenSocket->Listen();

while(running)
{
    Socket *socket = &listenSocket->Accept();
    mutex.lock();
    clients.push_back(new Client(socket,  clientID));
    mutex.unlock();

    std::cout << "Client with id " << clientID << " connected!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

    clientID++;
}
```

Now, the first client accepts fine and the WSAGetLastError() returns 0, but after the first one connected, even if I dont trying to connect another it just keep writing in the console 10093, which means the Accept() in the loop stoppped blocking and for some reason wont accept properly. I read online that this error caused by not calling WSAStartup() but I did called it in the socket's constructor and it did accept in the first time.

Comment: Are you possibly calling WSACleanup somewhere, like in a destructor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

10093 is `WSANOTINITIALISED`, which means that either:

- a socket call is being made before `WSAStartup()` has been called at all.
- a socket call is being made after `WSACleanup()` has been called as many times as `WSAStartup()` was called.

Based on the code you have provided, it appears that `Socket::Accept()` is returning a `Socket` object by value instead of a `Socket*` pointer.  If so, then `Accept()` is creating a temporary `Socket` that goes out of scope immediately after `Socket *socket` is assigned.  Chances are that the `Socket` destructor is calling `WSACleanup()` when it should not be.  Calls to `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()` must be balanced at all times.

The best time to call `WSAStartup()` is during program startup, not inside in an object's constructor. And likewise, the best time to call `WSACleanup()` is during program cleanup before exit, not inside of an object's destructor.

Comment: in my case, I called ```WSACleanup()``` function **before** ```closesocket()```. So it gave me ```WSANOTINITIALISED``` error as mentioned here:)

Answer (score 13):

I was having the exact same problem while programming a cross platform socket application. It was working fine on linux and OS X but I was getting this error 10093 on windows. To fix it add this code before calling any of the winsock functions:

```
    #ifdef WIN32
        // Initialize Winsock
        int iResult;
        WSADATA wsaData;
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            std::cout << "WSAStartup failed: " << iResult << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    #endif
```

Comment: thank you - this was the issue that I was having - I was not performing the WSAStartup() in all branches of an if/else