# C++ program cann't connect to server because of error code 10093

Tags: c++, sockets, dll, server, winsock

I am using a DLL file in my project which is used in some other projects for many years, and I am sure that it works correctly.

When I call method `f1` from the DLL, which opens a client session and connects to a server, I face a system socket error. When I use `WSAGetLastError()`, it returns 10093.

I googled the error and some suggestion was about using `"netsh winsock reset"` to correct some misconfigurations in the OS. But `reset` may change some configurations that I need.

My OS is Windows 10, and I just call `f1` method.

How can I fix this error without changing unrelated configuration in my system? I can't make any changes in the DLL's methods.

Comment: This answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477148/c-winsock-10093-error suggests that the error is in the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Winsock is reference counted. A successful call to `WSAStartup()` increments the refcount, and a successful call to `WSACleanup()` decrements the refcount.

Error code 10093 is `WSANOTINITIALIZED`, which means the DLL is trying to make a Winsock call (other than `WSAStartup()`) while the refcount is 0. So, either `WSAStartup()` has not been called at all yet, or `WSACleanup()` has been called at least as many times as `WSAStartup()` was called (maybe more).

Either way, this is a coding bug, but whether it is a bug in the EXE or the DLL, there is no way for us to say since we can't see your code. This is not something that `netsh winsock reset` will fix. It needs to be fixed in the code that is causing it to happen in the first place.